# modal bootstrap con vuejs

Tags: php, bootstrap, vue.js, modal

Tengo un PHP donde tengo codigo HTML y este está enlazado con un archivo JS donde codifico vuejs.

las variables `{{idagenda}}`, `{{nrosininformar}}`, `{{nrofinalizados}}` declaradas en el html principal sí responden a la reactividad de vuejs, pero cuando desde ese html hago clic en un botón que muestra un modal de Bootstrap, las variables `{{idagenda}}`, `{{nrosininformar}}`, `{{nrofinalizados}}` declaradas en este modal no toman los cambios.

Este es el HTML que activa el modal dentro del PHP

```
    <p>{{idagenda}}</p>
    <p>{{nrosininformar}}</p>
    <p>{{nrofinalizados}}</p>
    <div onclick="pruebavuejs()" class="button btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalprueba" type="button">
        presiona
    </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalprueba1" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="mmodalprueba1Label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content" style='border-color: red;'>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <p>{{idagenda}}</p>
                <p>{{nrosininformar}}</p>
                <p>{{nrofinalizados}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

esta función está en un archivo JS

```
function pruebavuejs(){
    vueEspecialista.idagenda="6666";
}
```

Este es un método de un archivo JS que está declarado en el HTML

let vueEspecialista = new Vue(
{
el : "#vueEspecialista",
data :{
idagenda : "0000",
nrosininformar : 0,
nrofinalizados : 0,
},
methods :{
pruebavuejs : function(){
vueEspecialista.idagenda="6666";
},

```
       contadores : function(){
            var params      =   new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('estado','1');
   axios.post(config.especialistaController+'contadores',params).then(function(response) 
          {
                vueEspecialista.nrosininformar = response.data[0].pendiente;
                vueEspecialista.nrofinalizados = response.data[0].finalizada;
            })
        },

    },
    mounted: function(){
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            vueEspecialista.contadores();
        });
    }
});
```